# lucene/solr norm: avoid short length fields to rank inappropriately high

Tags: solr, lucene, normalization

Using norm when indexing is great, my problem is that very short fields rank inappropriately high. Example:

```
doc1 : tf(200) out of 1.000 
doc2 : tf(150) out of 500
```

doc2 will score higher and its great.

Problem is when I have:

```
doc3 : tf(3) out of 4
```

which is not great in my case because it's a very rare document, let's say an exception.

I've read KinoSearch or someone suggesting to introduce a constant to kind of offset this issue. Any ideas on how I can still leverage full power of using norm and avoid this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `Similarity` class, extending `DefaultSimilarity`, and simply override the `lengthNorm` method.  The default lengthNorm implementation is pretty simple really:

```
public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
    final int numTerms;
    if (discountOverlaps)
        numTerms = state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap();
    else
        numTerms = state.getLength();
    return state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)));
}
```

Replace it with whatever algorithm makes sense in your case.  Really, the last line there is probably all you really need to worry about modifying, particularly `1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)`.  Two things to keep in mind here:

- Norms are compressed in a very lossy fashion (about 1 significant decimal digit!) to conserve space.  Big differences matter, minor tweaks will tend to get lost.
- You will need to re-index.  Norms are stored at index time, rather than calculated at query time.

You can [set Solr to use your Similarity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity) in your schema, like:

```
<similarity class="this.is.my.CustomSimilarity"/>
```